# App runs perfect on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android

I am newbie in android programming. I have to make an app for my thesis. So i made the program and test it on VM and all was fine, but when i tried to run it on real device the program did not work. My project is to make an app that reads data from Arduino and plot them on a graph. When i test it on real device my app could not  read the data. From the side of Arduino i saw that the connection was established.

Thank you for any advice-help.

MY code for connection is:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       try {
            return downloadContent(params[0]);
       } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.";
       }
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       // Toast.makeText(graphActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        textStatus.setText(result);
     //  myNum= Double.parseDouble(result);
     //   mytime= mytime+1;
      //  series.appendData(new DataPoint(mytime*1d ,myNum),true,28800);
    }
}

private String downloadContent(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    int length = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = convertInputStreamToString(is, length);
        return contentAsString;
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream stream, int length) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    char[] buffer = new char[length];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or crashes?

Comment: if i don't comment the lines in "onPostExecute" ,I get FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "Unable to retrieve data. URL may be invalid.". Maybe because it cant read something from arduino. I forgot to mention that arduino and  real device are in the same network. I do not know if it matters.

Comment: Do you have all of the correct permissions in the manifest? Are you sure you're using the local Wi-Fi and not a cellular connection?

Comment: I think yes. I am using  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: Your stream reading isn't correct at all. You are reading with an arbitrary length buffer, and then creating a string (which would have null characters at the end)

Comment: Which is the proper way to do it? The point is that the app works fine in VM with this code, but in real device have problem.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to say that the problem solved. The code  runs perfect with no changes. The problem was from the arduino side. I made some changes to arduino code and BOOM... it works :D :). If someone want to use the code  its ok. Runs either on AVD either on real device.